# Django rest framework APIView register route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am not able to register an `APIView` to my url routes.

Code from views :

```
class PayOrderViewSet(APIView):
    queryset = PayOrder.objects.all()
```

Code from urls :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'document/payorder', PayOrderViewSet)
```

This newly created url doesn't exist at all.

What is solution for this?

Comment: Add a trailing slash to the end of the url in your browser and see if it works.

Comment: Still same, not found :/

Comment: can you post your urls.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routers won't work with [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/). They only work with [ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and their derivatives.

You likely want:

```
class PayOrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
```

Comment: No need to quote. `Routers` expects API/data that are provided by `Viewset` but aren't available with `APIView`.

Answer (score 8):

Routers and APIViews (generic or otherwise) are two different ways to create API endpoints. Routers work with viewsets only.

In your code, you are although trying to create a viewset for a router your code is extending APIView class.

Your problem will be taken care by what @linovia has suggested in his asnwer. I would suggest it will be good idea to understand the difference between those two.

**GenericViewSet** inherits from GenericAPIView but does not provide any implementations of basic actions. Just only get_object, get_queryset.

**ModelViewSet** inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions. In other words you dont need implement basic actions as list, retrieve, create, update or destroy. Of course you can override them and implement your own list or your own create methods.

Read More about [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and [Generic Class Based APIViews](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) :

Answer (score 0):

For `ViewSet` you use `router` for url register and for `APIView` you need to add `path` to `urlpatterns`. Next example should help:

```
from post.api.views import UniquePostViewSet
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from post.api.views import FileUploadView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('UniquePost', UniquePostViewSet, base_name='uniquepostitem')

urlpatterns = [
    path('demo', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='demo'),  
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```